# "Terminologie" vs "Fachsprache"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Ich werde mir ein Wörterbuch, in dem man alle medizinischen
>   Terminologien beherrschen kann, kaufen.

I would like to know if the word *Terminologie* is correct in this context. And there's another word that's also closer to the same word, yet its in German which is *Fachsprache*. Can I use them interchangeably or one is used differently from the other?

Comment: I suppose you meant *Termini* (medical terms, not medical terminologies).

Comment: I always hear "medical terminology" more often than " medical term"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While **Terminologie** is technically correct in this context, I would use the term **Fachbegriffe**.

P.S. I'm not sure beherrschen is the right word for this sentence. You're not looking for a book where you can *master* all medical terminology; you're looking for a book in which you can *look up* all medical terminology.

I would write:

> Ich werde mir ein Wörterbuch, in dem man alle medizinischen
>   Fachbegriffe nachschlagen kann, kaufen.

Comment: Thanks! I saw "Fachbegriff" too but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the relation between *Terminologie* and *Fachsprache*, Wikipedia says: "Terminologie ist die Menge aller Fachausdrücke (Termini) eines Fachgebiets. Sie ist Teil der Fachsprache, die zusätzlich über andere charakteristische Merkmale, etwa Phraseologie oder Grammatik, verfügt."